# Select Distinct and sequence at the same time

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct

How can I able to use `Distinct` on select statement along with a sequence on SQL Server

I try this sub-query but no luck I get error of

> NEXT VALUE FOR function is not allowed in check constraints, default objects, computed columns, views, user-defined functions, user-defined aggregates, user-defined table types, sub-queries, common table expressions, derived tables or return statements.

```
 Select Distinct (Select
                  Next Value for dbo.P_PM_TBlIF240_SEQ , 'PH70', LEFT(ToolID, LEN(ToolID) - 2) as TOOLID, UsedLife, GETDATE(), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'PH70-TA' 
            From
                    Machine_ToolItem_Relationship ) from Machine_ToolItem_Relationship
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Some theories: You could try putting `next value` in a `CROSS APPLY`. If that didn't work you could try wrapping it up in a scalar function and using cross apply on the scalar function. Otherwise you'd need to load the results into a table and apply the sequence to the table row by row I guess.

Comment: Might be an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)... [Edit] the question and provide a [example]. That is, the DDL (`CREATE` statements) of the table and the sequence, DML (`INSERT` statemens) with sample data for the table and the desired result with that sample data as tabular text. Do not use screenshots or other images for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve thank for the help @Nick.McDermaid  my final query looks like this.

```
Select
    Next Value for dbo.P_PM_TBlIF240_SEQ , 'PH70', LEFT(ToolID, LEN(a.ToolID) - 2) as TOOLID, a.UsedLife, GETDATE(), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'PH70-TA' 
    from (Select
    Distinct  LEFT(ToolID, LEN(ToolID) - 2) as TOOLID, UsedLife 
    from Machine_ToolItem_Relationship) as a
```